# Multiple change of variables in integral to difference between variables

Tags: integration, combinatorics, distribution-theory, dirac-delta

When changing variables in multiple integrals one needs to find the Jacobian matrix of the transformation

$$\int dx_1\cdots dx_n f(x_1,...,x_n)=\int dy_1\cdots dy_n f(y_1,...,y_n)\left|\frac{\partial(x_1,...,x_n)}{\partial(y_1,...,y_n)}\right|$$

However, in the problem I am facing I don't understand why this does not work. I have to evaluate the integral

$$\int_0^1 dx_1\cdots dx_{2n} \delta(x_{i_1}-x_{i_1+1}+x_{i_2}-x_{i_2+1})\cdots \delta(x_{i_{n-1}}-x_{i_{n-1}+1}+x_{i_{n}}-x_{i_{n}+1})$$

with non-repetitive indices $i_1,...,i_n$. I want to substitute $y_i=x_i-x_{i+1}$ in the above integral. For this the Jacobin becomes simply $\frac{1}{2}$ and the multiple-integral factorizes to double integrals, but the result I am getting is definitely wrong. For simplicity I assume $i_{k-1}\pm1\neq i_k$ for any $k$. There must be some combinatorial problem of how the indices are arranged but I don't see it anywhere. Most likely I need something similar to [Integration of Dirac delta over finite interval](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2787227/integration-of-dirac-delta-over-finite-interval), but for arbitrary indices.

Any help for even small n<6 is helpful. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you should choose a managable $n$ and explicitly write out all the combinations to see that you understand the combinatorics correctly.