# Partition of n into k parts with at most m

Tags: number-theory, summation, integer-partitions, kronecker-delta

I ran into a problem in evaluating a sum over kronecker delta. I want to evaluate

$$\sum_{\ell_1,...,\ell_{2m}=1}^s\delta_{\ell_1+\ell_3+...+\ell_{2m-1},\ell_2+\ell_4+...+\ell_{2m}}$$

My approach was to change indices to the sum in the delta, i.e $\ell=\ell_1+\ell_3+...+\ell_{2m-1}$ and $\ell'=\ell_2+\ell_4+...+\ell_{2m}$, but then I need to know how many times each $\ell$ occurs as such a sum, i.e. I need to know $p_k(n;s)$, which I define as the number of partitions of $\ell$ into $m$ parts with the largest element at most $s$. Then the sum becomes

$$\sum_{\ell_1,...,\ell_{2m}=1}^s\delta_{\ell_1+\ell_3+...+\ell_{2m-1},\ell_2+\ell_4+...+\ell_{2m}}=\sum_{\ell=m}^{ms}p_m(\ell;s)$$

I need to include all permutations of the partition, for instance for $m=2$ I want

$$p_2(\ell;s)=\left\{\begin{array}{cc}\ell-1&\ell\leq s+1\\2s+1-\ell&\ell>s+1\end{array}\right.$$

which comes from the following partitions for $s=6$:
$$
5=1+4=2+3=3+2=4+1\\
6=1+5=2+4=3+3=4+1=5+1\\
7=1+6=2+5=3+4=4+3=5+2=6+1\\
8=2+6=3+5=4+4=5+3=6+2\\
9=3+6=4+5=5+4=6+3$$

Then for $m=3$ the following partitions are needed for $s=3$ (smaller $s$ for simplicity)

$$
3=1+1+1\\
4=1+1+2=1+2+1=2+1+1\\
5=1+1+3=1+3+1=3+1+1=1+2+2=2+1+2=2+2+1\\
6=1+2+3=3+1+2=2+3+1=3+2+1=1+3+2=2+1+3=2+2+2\\
7=2+2+3=2+3+2=3+2+2=1+3+3=3+1+3=3+3+1\\
8=2+3+3=3+2+3=3+3+2
$$

But I don't see the functional dependence yet. In general, $p_k(n;s)$ is definetely non-trivial. Does anyone have any tips how to evaluate this function? At least for n<=5 for starters?

PS.
I have a way to evaluate the leading term of the sum, by changing the kronecker delta to dirac delta, then chaning variables and integrating integrals of the same kind as listed here
[Integration of Dirac delta over finite interval](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2787227/integration-of-dirac-delta-over-finite-interval)
, but I want all terms if possible to said sum.

Thanks for any help!